# bar chart legend color change

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4.2

I would like to change the color of bar chart in extjs. 
I can changing the bar with renderer in series, but now I would like to change the legend's color too.
Here is the piece of code:

```
           .. series : [ {
                type : 'bar',
                axis : 'bottom',
                gutter : 0,
                groupGutter : 0,
                yField : this.fields,
                title : this.fieldTitles,
                colorArrayStyle : ['#FFF']
                stacked : true,
                fill: true,
                scope: this,
                renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
                    var color = fieldColors[index];                    
                    attr.fill = color;
                    return attr;
               }, ....
```

How can I change the legend's color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it by overriding the [`getLedengColor`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.series.Bar-method-getLegendColor) method.

Comment: @VaheAkhsakhalyan So, did you try this method?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

Get the chart

`var chart = Ext.getCmp('yourchart');`

then:

```
chart.series.items[0].colorArrayStyle = ['#97d856', '#4a96db', '#f05665', '#fe9f2f','#fec27b'];
```

After that you should need to redraw the chart like this:

```
chart.redraw();
```